# Java - changing coded design to my own design?

Tags: java, user-interface

If I wanted to take this code: 
https://pastebin.com/et3bMjyY

but use my own design instead, how would I go about doing that?

By that, I mean:
This is the original design, which was created through code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrvXM.jpg
This is my design, which was created through the "Design" tab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVNF3.jpg

Like for example, I commented out the block of code (pasted below), which I can clearly see is something I don't want. But I'm not entirely sure what I can take out and what I can't

```
    resultJText.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 20));
    resultJText.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    resultJText.setEnabled(false);
    resultJText.setHorizontalAlignment(4);
    resultJText.setDisabledTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Any suggestions on what I would change in the source code of the original design to make it work the same but look like mine? (I know the buttons are slightly different but just ignore that) Or is this not possible without a total re-work?

Comment: GUI designers are good for playing around, but for any serious work you need to do it through code. Either rebuild the whole thing with the designer, or learn to create a GUI through code.

Comment: Extract the logic and then use javafx to create your own gui design